# Specify cookies valid (sub)domains

Tags: php, cookies, subdomain

Every answer I've found, always suggest to set the cookies domain to `example.com` to make the cookies available also in the subdomains.

But I want to specify the subdomains, or better, exclude `static.example.com`. I don't want to send the cookies on that subdomain, since it is used only for static content.

It is possible? I set the cookies with PHP `setcookie()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only solution is, to url structure. For example:

```
host1.dyn.example.com
host2.dyn.example.com
host3.dyn.example.com
```

and

```
host1. static.example.com
host2. static.example.com
```

Now you can set your cookie to *.dyn.example.com* and the cookie is only available at this subdomains.

**OR**

(not my favorite)

```
<?php

foreach(array("dyn1.example.com", "dyn2.example.com") as $host){
setcookie("name", $value, 0, /, $host, true, true);
}

?>
```